# How to Copy the fill pattern of a cell to a shape?

Tags: excel, vba, cell, shapes

I have been writing a code that is copying the color of the cell and pasting it to the relevant shape. I am able to copy the color. However, it seems more complicated to copy the fill pattern of the cell.
The problem i have faced is that the pattern parameter of a cell is, for example, "xlLightHorizontal" and the same pattern for a shape is "msoPatternNarrowHorizontal". Both draw the same fill pattern but have different names.

How i copy the color and fill pattern of the cell:

```
modelText(3, 1) = Sheets("Orders").Cells(row, j + 1).Interior.Color
modelText(3, 2) = Sheets("Orders").Cells(row, j + 1).Interior.Pattern
modelText(3, 3) = Sheets("Orders").Cells(row, j + 1).Interior.PatternColor
```

How i assign the color and the fill pattern to the shape:

```
 With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .ForeColor.RGB = modelText(3, 1)
        .BackColor.RGB = modelText(3, 3)
        .Patterned (msoPatternLightHorizontal)
 End With
```

Note that:

`Cells(row, j + 1).Interior.Pattern`  returns `xlLightHorizontal`

Where

`ShapeRange.Fill.Patterned`  does not accept `xlLightHorizontal` as an input parameter

Is there anyway that you know to copy the fill pattern of a cell to a shape?

Comment: Try it manually while recording a macro - for me it didn't offer the ability to add diagonal lines or hatching patterns to a shape. It did offer a picture though, so take a screen grab of the pattern you want & use that ??

Comment: I have recorded a macro for both cases. That's how i recognized that they require two different variable for the same pattern on a cell and a drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to find a solution. It looks like that the two set of enumeration are not matching. I hope you do have a very limited set of pattern you would like to use. In this case I would make a table of pairs (numbers to the same or at least similar pattern) of the enums to make the conversion. I have not better idea. Sorry.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.msopatterntype?view=office-pia and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.constants?view=excel-pia

Comment: Yes you are right. Creating an object which is mapping two parameters might work as a round about.